# Goodman - C wire connection

Tags: furnace, thermostat-c-wire

I have an older unit Goodman furnace with a c-wire that isn't connected to the unit. In order to install a wifi thermostat to supply continuous power I need to connect the c wire. I see spots for the W, G, and R wire connections, but no c wire. An alternative would be to do a power adapter at the thermostat, but I'm hoping for some guidance on where I could connect the c-wire for power. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo that shows where both wires heading off to the air conditioner connect at? You have central air conditioning, even, I take it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 24 volt transformer in the top-left corner of the photo. It has a red wire from one side of the secondary (24 volt side) going into the multi-position plug onto the circuit board. The other secondary wires are blue; it looks like there are three and one of them is a jumper down to the mounting foot of the transformer. Based on that I'll say C ("common") in this unit is wired to the chassis.

To verify use a volt meter in AC mode. Measure voltage from R to chassis (should be about 24-30 volts) and W to chassis (should be about 0 volts). Note that because this is all in the blower compartment there is a safety switch you'll have to override in order to turn on the power for this test.

Since there's apparently no terminal designated for the thermostat C wire, in your case you could attach the C wire to one of those screws where a blue wire attaches to the sheet metal.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I realized the adapter was probably the safer solution for a novice.

Comment: @aeroknase If you'll take the [tour], you'll see that the appropriate way of saying "thanks" around here is to click the up vote arrow for every answer that you find helpful, and click the check mark next to the answer that helps you the _most_ (or only one, as the case may be).